# Where is better to keep the instance of data source object of Table View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'd like to have a separate class that conforms to UITableViewDataSource protocol and works with data objects.
Where is better to keep, allocate and initialize the instance of this class?
If I do this in `ViewDidLoad` method of Table View Controller subclass, that connected to Storyboard, the instance of data source is deallocated after method `ViewDidLoad` is finished.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyTableViewDataSource* myDataSource = [[MyTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = myDataSource;
} // self.tableView.dataSource is deallocated
```

Will it be better solution to create a strong property of data source object in of Table View Controller subclass, that connected to storyboard and than allocate and initialize instance of data source in `ViewDidLoad`?

```
@interface MyTableVC : UITableViewController
@property  (strong, nonatomic)  MyTableViewDataSource *myDataSource;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myDataSource = [[MyTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = myDataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's being deallocated is because the `UITableView` does not retain it:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UITableViewDataSource > dataSource
                     ^^^^^^
```

This is normal with delegates, in order to avoid retain cycles.

Therefore if you want to create a new object to act as your data source, you will need to retain it, as per your 2nd code snippet.

Comment: The application is crashed if I use the code you've suggested - '@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UITableViewDataSource > dataSource' . I work with ARC.

Comment: I was showing you the declaration of the `dataSource` property on `UITableView`, not suggesting code changes.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand.